# Unable to read the console values Java

Tags: java, maven, process, null, console

So, I want to run a jar using java, get the output, and store it to a string. 
I can see via the console that jar runs without any issues and I can see the output via console. However, the console values are not getting stored and returns null on printing.
What am I doing wrong? Please help.

The jdk used is jdk 11.
The code I have written so far:

```
    public static void runTest(String Id, String token) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "./lib/Myjar.jar", Id, token);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
    Process proc = pb.start();

    System.out.println("Job running");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
        builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    String result = builder.toString();

    proc.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Job finished");
    System.out.println("Output:\n" + result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BufferedReader is empty and therefore you can't read anything in the while-loop. At the end, the StringBuilder is an empty object and the result String has no value.

Here is an example how you can read the Output from one jar in another Java Program:

First program: myjava.jar

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World"); 
}
```

And then the Java Code which is reading the output from myjava.jar:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String token = "t";
    String Id = "x";
    runTest(Id, token);
}

public static void runTest(String Id, String token) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "./myjava.jar", Id, token);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE);
    Process proc = pb.start();

    System.out.println("Job running");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try(InputStream  in = proc.getInputStream(); 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in)) {
        while(scanner.hasNext()) { 
            builder.append(scanner.next());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String result = builder.toString();
    proc.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Job finished");
    System.out.println("Output:\n" + result);
}
```